# Adding functions to Thread class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a simple clock class to simulate time I need it to run at the same time as other threads so I made it threaded I have a few extra methods that get units of time used in my system but now I have changed it to a threaded system I can't seem to get hold of them.

Here is the code for the clock class

```
public class Clock extends Thread {
    private Integer seconds;
    private Integer minute;
    private Integer hour;

    public Clock()
    {
        setClock(0,0,0);
    }

    public void setClock(int hr, int min, int sec)
    {
        if(0 <= hr && hr < 24)
        {
            hour = hr;
        }
        else
        {
            hour = 0;
        }

        if(0 <= min && min < 60)
        {
            minute = min;
        }
        else
        {
            minute = 0;
        }

        if(0 <= sec && sec < 60)
        {
            seconds = sec;
        }
        else
        {
            seconds = 0;
        }
    }

    public void tick()
    {
        this.seconds += 5;

        this.minute += (int)(this.seconds/60);

        this.seconds = this.seconds % 60;

        this.hour += (int)(this.minute/60);

        this.minute = this.minute % 60;

        this.hour = this.hour % 24;

    }

    public int getMin()
    {
        return this.minute;
    }

    public int getHour()
    {
        return this.hour;
    }

    public String getTime()
    {
        return minute.toString() + "m" + seconds.toString() + "s";
    }

    public void run()
    {
        tick();
    }

}
```

The three functions above the run are the ones causing the problem I have looked for a solution but can't find one I thought that ´extends´ was like inheritance and it would add those methods to the Thread.

Here is the thread declaration

```
Thread clock1 = new Clock();
```

I start it in the normal way of doing start then join as I am running multiple threads.

```
Thread TestJunc4 = new CarPark(100,TestTemp4,clock1);
```

I pass the thread into the other threads that need it then try and make a call like this , I am just giving the top part of the statement as the rest doesn't seem important.

```
while(clock.getHour() != 1)
```

The problem is I can't call the get methods like the ´getHour´ I am using net beans and when I get the list of functions they don't show up in it and if I add them manual I get the error that it can't find them.

Comment: And, what's the problem?

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem a little bit more?

Comment: Do Clock clock1 = new Clock(); Because Clock extends Thread it can be used as thread too. But everywhere, where you need your impl. you have to use Clock instead of thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Clock class is extending Thread. So and instance of Clock is a Thread too.
This means everywhere, where the java api expects an thread you can pass your clock object. But when you need special methods of your impl. your have to pass it as clock.

```
Clock clock1 = new Clock();
```

Comment: Thanks for that it looks like it works can't believe I didn't try that.

Comment: Wait till you get abstract generic problems or doing polymorphism ;) Dont forget to mark my answer as solution.